# automatically set type of element for implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm passing an implicit intent for handling different type of objects via this intent

```
Intent openPdfFileIntent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
openPdfFileIntent.setType("text/plain"); // here do we have to set every possible types of data ??? or android have any other apis for determining which type  of this data is
String str = "this is the passed string";
openPdfFileIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,str);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openPdfFileIntent,"Choose for completing action"));
```

its working fine but i want to know do android is smart enough to automatically determine by observing the objet to handle action using appropriate app (dynamically set the mimeType by observing the name of object)

in the above intent the `setType` for handling the object`is`text/plain`so what if the`object` which have to be handle is not text type it could be anything else like  image , mp3 , mp4 , doc  file , html , etc  do we have to determine mime types  manually   by checking the object's extension and using (if, else) for setting the type of object

hey guys if my question is hard to understand then please let me know , i'll improve it , this time am not able to explain exactly what i want .

Comment: Did you try by opening different files viz music, video, doc text by not specifying mime-type, are all these files getting opened correctly? I has always set setType on Intent when I had opened any file. If its not working then you should have to specify it explicitly according to file type.

Comment: off course i havent tried to open them without specifying the setType , i tried once with text/plain type  , brother see my question  i want to know do we have to specify each mimeType for possible objects ??? or android have any apis for selecting itself the appropriate app for handling the object